# Turning mindmap to animated slide

Tags: beamer, animations, mindmaps

I would like to turn this mindmap to an animation where e.g. the main items appear on the first click, and then each item has its children appearing on click. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Mindmap}{}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.5, every node/.style={transform shape}]
  \path [
    mindmap,
    text = white,
    level 1 concept/.append style =
      {font=\Large\bfseries, sibling angle=90},
    level 2 concept/.append style =
      {font=\normalsize\bfseries},
    level 3 concept/.append style =
      {font=\small\bfseries},
    tex/.style     = {concept, ball color=blue,
      font=\Huge\bfseries},
    engines/.style = {concept, ball color=green!50!black},
    formats/.style = {concept, ball color=blue!50!black},
    systems/.style = {concept, ball color=red!90!black},
    editors/.style = {concept, ball color=orange!90!black}
  ]
  node [tex] {\TeX} [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black, nodes={engines}] {
      node {Engines} [clockwise from=90]
        child { node {\TeX} }
        child { node {pdf\TeX} }
        child { node {\XeTeX} }
        child { node {Lua\TeX} }}
    child [concept color=blue, nodes={formats}] {
      node {Formats} [clockwise from=300]
        child { node {\LaTeX} }
        child { node {Con\TeX t} }}
    child [concept color=red, nodes={systems}] {
      node {Systems} [clockwise from=210]
        child { node {\TeX Live} [clockwise from=300]
          child { node {Mac \TeX} }}
        child { node {MiK\TeX} [clockwise from=60]
          child { node {Pro \TeX t} }}}
    child [concept color=orange, nodes={editors}] {
      node {Editors} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Credits: Stefan Kottwitz

Comment: Your code is not compilable. Please correct it.

Comment: As mentioned at the end, please download the missing file dtklogos.sty available at http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/usergrps/dante/dtk-1.32/dtklogos.sty and it should compile (It works for me). Let me know the specific error in case it still does not compile.

Comment: Thanks to @samcarter. Answered at [topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1165#a1373](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1165#a1373)

Comment: Even with this, it is not compilable. That said, this package `dtklogos.sty` is useless in your example.

Comment: Yes, `dktlogos.sty` is irrelevant for this specific piece of code. I am not sure why it does not work for you. Maybe some other package is missing in your case.

Comment: Yes, this package works for me, but since it is not useful in your example and the principle of the questions is to give a code that works with the minimum of package, you might as well remove it.